# Ajv: how to make a property nullable conditionally depending on other property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, validation, ajv

I have an object that can be in one of 4 states:

1. `{"A": "something", "B": [{"C": "D"}]}`
2. `{"A": "", "B": [{"C": "D"}]}`
3. `{"A": "something", "B": null}`
4. `{"A": "", "B": null}`

In my Ajv schema validation I want to make the property `"B"` `nullable: true` only if the property `"A"` is **not** an empty string.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

**I hope the below helpers function helps you. You can make changes in assignment value as you need**

```js
function mappNullable(obj, nonNullable, nullableProperty) { 
   if(obj[nonNullable] != '') { 
      obj[nullableProperty] = {nullable: true};
   }
   return;
}
const t1 = {"A": "something", "B": [{"C": "D"}]};
const t2 = {"A": "", "B": [{"C": "D"}]};
const t3 = {"A": "something", "B": null};
const t4 = {"A": "", "B": null};
mappNullable(t1, "A", "B");
mappNullable(t2, "A", "B");
mappNullable(t3, "A", "B");
mappNullable(t4, "A", "B");
console.log(t1);  // {"A": "something", "B": {nullable: true}};
console.log(t2); // {"A": "", "B": [{"C": "D"}]};
console.log(t3); // {"A": "something", "B": {nullable: true}};
console.log(t4); //  {"A": "", "B": null};
```